# quartz-scheduler failed to trigger regularly

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I am using quartz-scheduler for my Java application. I scheduled 40 schedules, every day more than 50 jobs have to be trigger but after 2, 3 days some triggers are failed to trigger.

Answer (score 0):

You should log you scheduler time and tasks,  after 2 or 3  days may be there some conflicts between two or more scheduler.

Comment: Im logging every trigger time and job id but its not getting trigger its self then how can i see logs